# How to add and delete segments in a viewcontroller by clicking add button an delete button created in the same viewcontroller?

Tags: ios, swift

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

// @IBAction func Btndel(_ sender: Any) {
//}

var Str:String?


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let items = [Str]
    let SegM = UISegmentedControl(items:items as Any as? [Any])
    SegM.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

    SegM.frame=CGRect(x: 70, y: 130, width: 100, height: 50)
    SegM.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
    SegM.backgroundColor = .orange
    SegM.tintColor = .white

    self.view .addSubview(SegM)



    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

@IBAction func Btnadd(_ sender: Any)
{
var Str = 0;Str += 1

}


override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

How to add and delete segments in a viewcontroller by clicking add button an delete button created in the same viewcontroller

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol try this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert segment by **insertSegment** method of UISegmentedControl and you can delete segment by **removeSegment** method. Let me take an example.

I create **segmentController** class and its UI in a storyboard. 
Below is UI screenshot. In the storyboard, You can see two buttons Insert (+) and Remove (-) and UISegmentedControl. Insert button will insert segment at a specific position and Remove button will remove the segment at a specific position.

[image: segmantController UI]

Below is code of **segmentController** class.

```
class segmentController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var segementControl: UISegmentedControl!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
    @IBAction func remove(_ sender: Any) {
        segementControl.removeSegment(at: segementControl.numberOfSegments-1, animated: true)
    }
    @IBAction func insert(_ sender: Any) {
        segementControl.insertSegment(withTitle: "\(segementControl.numberOfSegments+1)", at: segementControl.numberOfSegments, animated: true)
    }

}
```

In the above code, on insert button click new segment will add at the last of segementControl. On remove button click the last segment will delete from segmentControl.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

**How to insert and remove(add or delete) segments in swift4**

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var segment1: UISegmentedControl!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}


@IBAction func insert(_ sender: Any) {

    segment1.insertSegment(withTitle: "\(segment1.numberOfSegments+1)", at: segment1.numberOfSegments, animated: true)


    }

    @IBAction func remove(_ sender: Any) {

    segment1.removeSegment(at: segment1.numberOfSegments-1, animated: true)
}
}
```